# How to set up virtual hosts when changed the default port(80) to 8080?

Tags: windows, apache, mamp, vhosts

I'm using MAMP on windows 10 and I couldn't start Apache server because of my default port(80) is used by System. So I changed the default port to 8080. But now I can't access my previously set up virtual host sites. Please help me

I already tried this :

1) MAMP\bin\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
Listen 8080
```

2) MAMP\bin\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
Listen 8080
```

3)hosts file

```
127.0.0.1:8080       mygym.test
```

4) MAMP\bin\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "E:/MAMP/htdocs/mygym/system"
    ServerName mygym.test
</VirtualHost>
```

now when I typed as mygym.test in the URL tab It comes a 404 error

*No webpage was found for the web address: http://mygym.test/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

> 3)hosts file
>
> 127.0.0.1:8080       mygym.test

The hosts file is for host name resolution only. You cannot put port numbers in there. the browser is what selects the port to choose.

Instead try `127.0.0.1       mygym.test` in hosts file and try `http://mygym.test:8080` in browser.